# Biostar 2 suprema hidden database

Tags: biometrics

Hellow devs, I kind of develop an app to get reports from the sql biometric biostar 2 suprema  in python i get this project for an uncompleted project in job and i had to make it work, i saw a connection in the code it was in mysql.

This connection is made and the structure is that it creates a table automatically every month with the year and month of in the name, due the bad implementation of the website is not easy to get all the data from a report, is not like a real report is more like a visualitation.

The code is perfect now and the connection is working well, the problem is everytime there is a problem (missing data due blackouts or any other failure), the web app of biostar 2 always display all the data even the missing one from the report, even when i check the data base in mysql the one the python app use to get data has this data missing but in the web app is displaying like it was in the data base.

Does this biometric from suprema has a "main" database? If it has can it be accesable?

Thanks for reading.